# alias for python class in another module

Tags: python

For example:

I have a module A what contains class CLASS,
also I have module B what uses class CLASS as parameter in its methods
and I have module C what uses module B. So I should import A.CLASS to make it
possible to pass CLASS as parameter to methods from module B. But if I'll put module A
to another packages D.E.F... I'll get a really long import string

What is best way to make alias for CLASS in module B, to using B.someMethod(B.CLASS) and module
C knows nothing about module A.

Now I import A.Class in module B, and then use import B.CLASS in module C

.# File: a.py

```
class Klass(object):
    pass
```

.# File b.py

```
from a import Klass

def somemethod(foo):
    pass
```

.# File c.py

```
from b import somemethod
from b import Klass

somemethod(Klass.field)
```

Comment: `import A.B.C.D.E.F as G`?

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: Bad idea. Either D, E, F, etc. need to know about A and should import and use A explicitly, or the classes in A and B should be reorganized. What you're looking for is a breeding ground for initialization order bugs.

Comment: Note that you don't need to know anything about a class to pass around instances of the class. Unless you're actually passing the class itself as an argument to functions, you may not even need to import A at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to describe this situation, and I don't see any issue here:

> I have a module A what contains class CLASS

```
# File: a.py

class Klass(object):
    pass
```

> I have module B what uses class CLASS as parameter in its methods

```
# File b.py

from a import Klass

def somemethod(foo):
    pass

somemethod(Klass)
```

> I have module C what uses module B. So I should import A.CLASS to make it possible to pass CLASS as parameter to methods from module B.

```
# File c.py

from b import somemethod
from a import Klass

somemethod(Klass)
```

> Now I import A.Class in module B, and then use import B.CLASS in module C

Just import `A.Class` in `B`, since `B.Class` is the same as `A.Class`

Comment: Thank you, I do it exactly as it, I simply want to know: is it good or there are better ways?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you are doing here. Why do you feel this is the "wrong" way?